# Array concatenation in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

How we can concate two associative arrays??
For exapmle:
Array1

```
$numbers = array();
$numbers['id'] = 4;
$numbers['num'] = 391; 
$numbers['rupees'] = 'Adeel';
```

Array2

```
$numbers1 = array();
$numbers1['id'] = 5;
$numbers1['num'] = 392; 
$numbers1['name'] = 'shah';
```

The result should be something like this

```
id   num  name
4    391  Adeel
5    392  waqar
```

What should i do???

Comment: Concatenate how? Add all existing keys in order, even duplicates? Overwrite the keys in one with the keys in the other?

Comment: Can you give an example of what you want to see as the result?

Comment: yes Ignacio, Overwrite the keys in one with the keys in the other...

Comment: Your example shows two sets of data, rather than any overwriting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your example you don't need to concatenate them. You need to put them in the same array:

```
$numbers = array();
$numbers['id'] = 4;
$numbers['num'] = 391; 
$numbers['rupees'] = 'Adeel';

$numbers1 = array();
$numbers1['id'] = 5;
$numbers1['num'] = 392; 
$numbers1['name'] = 'shah';

$all[] = $numbers;
$all[] = $numbers1;
```

This way you will get something consistent with what you get when you fetch from a database.

Comment: Probably sensible to retain that `id` field as a key on `$all`.

Comment: @Alin Purcaru: Fine, but curious as to why not?

Comment: @Orbling I think he wants something similar to a database fetch result. Those arrays are rarely indexed by a value.

Comment: @Alin Purcaru: Granted, but usually people tend to index them by ID whilst reading them in, otherwise direct access is a pain.

Comment: @Alin Purcaru: That's alright, it's your answer (which I gave +1 to originally) - and the comments suffice to my slight alternation.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`array_merge()`](http://php.net/manual/function.array-merge.php):

```
$con_array = array_merge ($numbers, $number1);
```

This will give you `$con_array`:

```
Array
(
    [id] => 4
    [num] => 391
    [rupees] => Adeel
    [name] => Adeel
)
```

Comment: Note the updated question - it is not an `array_merge()` candidate.